# What research has been done into "emotion-driven" politics?

Tags: democracy, political-theory, political-system

[Byung-Chul Han](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byung-Chul_Han) and other authors have pointed out that political discourses are undergoing a transmutation from the style prevailing in the 1980s to the current one, where post-truth, emotion and social networks seem to have changed the strategies and discourses of political organizations.

Beyond opinions, I would like to know what quantitative work has been carried out by political scientists to confirm or disprove this type of reflections?

Comment: I would point to historian [Timothy Snyder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SI_ak30tFyg) who had risen to prominence since the Russian invasion of Ukraine. He specializes in Eastern European history which gave him a front row seat to Russia's post-truth society and how it has steadily exported this type of politics to the democratic west in recent years. The core of his analysis revolves around two concepts: "politics of ineveitability" and "politics of eternity" - the later in particular is a type of poltiics that discards truth and favors emotion / spectacle entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bit difficult to answer given that -- even with more language analysis tools -- it's harder to quantify emotions and then take the next step of connecting them to "the strategies and discourses of political organizations". For example, tweets clearly affect politicians and their decision-making however most politicians don't list out the tweets that affected their proposal or vote. *The short answer to your question seems to be not much **quantitative work***.

That being said, I think this is a really interesting topic and did find some slightly more data-driven articles and charts on the subject. If this is in the direction of what you were looking for, I'd be happy to continue updating this list as I (or others) find more...

- [Examining spread of emotional political content](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41599-021-00987-4#Sec10) (see fig. 3 and 4 for example)
- [Measuring emotion in political ads](https://journalistsresource.org/politics-and-government/negative-political-ads-effects-voters-research-roundup/) (seems like a great metric as it directly measures individual politicians and parties' use of emotional content). [This data](https://www.opensecrets.org/online-ads) (or [this](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1182087/political-advertising-spending-election-cycle-by-medium-united-states/)) could be pretty interesting if someone correlated it with emotional content in each of those organization's ads.
- [Analyzing emotion in political speeches](https://towardsdatascience.com/sentiment-analysis-of-political-speeches-using-hugging-faces-pipeline-feature-3109c121d351)
- [Inspecting sentiment in political tweets](https://towardsdatascience.com/twitter-political-compass-machine-a-nature-language-processing-approach-and-analysis-7e8152033495)
- [Emotional polarity in parliamentary debates](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0168843) (see figures section)

Note that most of these articles are focused on US politics. That may be because my search results are catered based on where I'm searching from but I think the bigger problem is just that there haven't been many broad or international quantitative studies done.

Key metrics worth considering...

- Advertising (quantity, audience, medium, spend, emotional content via [nlp](https://medium.com/neuronio/from-sentiment-analysis-to-emotion-recognition-a-nlp-story-bcc9d6ff61ae)).
- Speeches (quantity, audience, medium, emotional content via [nlp](https://medium.com/neuronio/from-sentiment-analysis-to-emotion-recognition-a-nlp-story-bcc9d6ff61ae)).
- Political social media posts (detected via [nlp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) and then measured for sentiment/emotion)

Related articles but not directly containing the quantitative metrics you're looking for...

- https://politicalmarketer.com/political-sentiment-analysis/
- https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2022.785453/full
- https://www.hotpolitics.eu/mpsa2020-panel2/